# Build and deploy specific revision number with TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

I'm just getting to grips with TeamCity and MSDeploy and have deployment to a dev environment triggered by SVN commit working nicely. The question I have is in terms of releasing to a test environment; I want to do this on demand and based on a specific revision number. What's the best way to configure a TeamCity build based on a user-defined revision?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Run Custom Build Dialog](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Run+Custom+Build+Dialog) in the TeamCity, and customize there **Changes to include** parameter, where you need to specify actually SVN revision to build.

Comment: What about doing so programmaticly? How would you tell Build B to build the source revision that was last successful for Build A?

Comment: @JosephLust, probably you can achieve the desired behaviour by creating a [Build Chain](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Chain). However, I would recomend you to create a separated question on SO to get more help.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on **Pin** functionality in TeamCity. You can pin a certain build and then deploy latest pinned build.

So you have a 'Create development build' task in TeamCity which deploys to dev environment and exposes artefacts. You can create another task in TeamCity that will use artefacts from latest pinned build in 'Create development build' task and deploy to your testing environment.

You can create yet another task that deploys to production latest pinned 'test' build. Rollback can be achieved by simply unpinning last pinned build.

You also have a history of deployed build.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, the only problem I have with that is if I'm using config transformations then the artifacts (namely the web.config) will be different in a development build versus a production build. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Troy Hunt - My TeamCity tasks are just running MSBUild scripts - I execute my transformations manually in MSBuild (+ any other environment-dependant changes).